# I want php to redirect to a directory I set when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two files named index.php and index2.php.
My problem is that; I don't want to have POST when I refresh the page in index2.php and I want to redirect to index.php again. How do I do that?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. Can you try and explain your question again?

Answer (score 0):

I think if I'm reading your question correctly, you want to send a post request to index.php without leaving your current page, which would be index2.php?

More context would help, but if running JavaScript on your page is possible, you could perform a post request via Ajax, and then redirect the user to index.php by changing the window location.

This is quite contradictory, as posting a form in standard html would achieve the same result.

Are you performing some other logic after the post which you want to happen on index2.php?

More info required please!

Comment: Do you have some example code for us to look at it? It may be easier to get a grasp of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The data from index.php is being POST when I refresh the page. I want to prevent this

Comment: index.php code: <form action="index2.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="username"></form> index2.php <?php if($_POST){$user = $_POST["username"];}?> html - > <span class ="userarea"><?php echo $user ?> </span>

Answer (score 0):

use sessions to store the number of tries of your condition on page2.

Do a check when loading page2 if it exists number tries redirect to page1. once you hit page 1 reset the number of tries if you need to

I'll let you write the PHP code yourself, but the logic goes like this

Page 1

```
// RESETS by: 
// if ($session[retries] > 2) {$session[retries] = 0}
```

Page 2

```
// load $session[retries], if not defined, than set default 0

// Increase number of retries
// if (someCondition) { $session[retires] += 1; }

// check the retries and redirect
// if ($isession[retries] > 2 ) { redirectToPage1; }
```

however the "refresh" behaviour you are describing is a little strange, it's best to use ajax.

Comment: index.php code:  `<form action="index2.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="username"></form>`  index2.php ` <?php if($_POST){$user = $_POST["username"];}?> html - > <span class ="userarea"><?php echo $user ?> </span>

Comment: The data from index.php is being POST when I refresh the page. I want to prevent this

Comment: yes, check session on index2 before your if($post) check.http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php